# Datepicker doesn't hide

Tags: jquery

i have i select like this:

```
<form:select path="critere" >
    <option value="0">Selectionner ...</option> 
    <option value="1">nom</option> 
    <option value="2">prénom</option> 
    <option value="3">cin</option> 
    <option value="4">date declaration perte</option> 
    <option value="5">date duplicata</option> 
    <option value="6">annexe administratif</option> 
</form:select>
```

with ajax call:

```
$( "#formSearch select" ).change(function() {         
    if( $("#formSearch select ").val() == 4 || $("#formSearch select ").val()==5 )
        $( "#formSearch input[type='text']" ).datepicker();
});
```

the problem is when i choose for the first time `value` `4` or `5` it's show me the calendar but after this when i choose `value` `1` or `2` it's show me the calendar again, so how to disable it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove datepicker when values 4 or 5 aren't selected. 
Remove it in *else* block like this:

```
$("input").datepicker("destroy");
```

There's an example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5N2n/).